# Print Report from 3 different combo box selection

Tags: sql, ms-access

I made a where condition for 2 combo box selection print on click  that,
[List]![EmployeeID] Between Forms!listact!combo1 And Forms!listact!combo2

now I wanted to and one more combo box please advice me how to

Comment: EmployeeID can't be between 3 values, so what would the role of the third combobox be? What exactly do you want to do with this 3rd combo box? Filter by another column or what?

Comment: Actually I'm Trying to print individual pay slips for selected EmpID/mm/yy . query name is LIST and the column1 employee name , column2 employeeid ,column3 month , column4 year , ext......... . FORM name is LISTACT then the Combo1 EmpID , Combo2 Month , Combo3 Year. on this situation how can I print the individual slip on click cmd

Comment: Your original condition filters for a range of employees. If you want only one employee why do you use range criteria? If you want multiple criteria then place appropriate parameter under each field. This is basic query design. Or if you prefer to build filter criteria in VBA and apply to report when opening, review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html